# AngularJS UI-GRID: editDropdownOptionsFunction and async $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown, ui-grid

I use ui-grid v3.2.9. I have grid with inline editing, one of editing cell - dropdown control. I want to get array for dropdown control every time when I click to this cells.  I try to use **editDropdownOptionsFunction** to download json for dropdown:

```
      columnDefs: [

        {
            name: 'serial',
            displayName: 'Serial',
            width: 100,
            enableCellEdit: true,
            editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
            editDropdownIdLabel: 'id',
            editDropdownValueLabel: 'id',
            editDropdownOptionsFunction: function(rowEntity, colDef){
                var res = [];
                $http.get('index.php?r=docs/serialsjson2&recid=' + rowEntity.id)
                    .success(function (data) {
                        res = data;                                     
                    });

                return res;
            }
        },

    ],
```

But as I understand $http.get finished too late and no fills dropdownarray.
Help me please. How do I need to do request data from server to dropdown widget in moment click?

Answer (score 0):

Loading the dropdown data happens after the data is returned into success function.Only means to get the data faster is  retriving data in simple steps without more loops or query operations[re-factor].

If that doesn't happen you can just try adding spinner(loader) in http interceptor and disable dropdown untill data is populated.

There are lot of ways in implementing spinners and hideoverlays for dropdown.
Below is one example link
 [Spinner and Overlay](https://github.com/AngularPlus/AngularPlus)

Answer (score 0):

you need to return the promise from $http:

```
return $http.get('index.php?r=docs/serialsjson2&recid=' + rowEntity.id).then(function (data) {
          return data;                                     
});
```

Also use .then instead of .success----success is deprecated